# Split A String at X, then at Y Value

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$Field = $FW->Encrypt("Test");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($Field);
echo "</pre>";
#  $IV_Count = strlen($Field['IV']);
#  $Key_Count = strlen($Field['Key']);
#  $Cipher_Count = strlen($Field['CipheredText']);

foreach ($Field AS $Keys => $Values){
    echo $Keys."Count = ".strlen($Values)."<br><br>";
}
```

The output is as:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [CipheredText] => x2nelnArnS1e2MTjOrq+wd9BxT6Ouxksz67yVdynKGI=
>     [IV] => 16
>     [Key] => III#TcTf‡eB12T
> )
>
> CipheredTextCount = 44
>
> IVCount = 2
>
> KeyCount = 16
> ```

The IV/KeyCount is always returning the same value regardless of the input. But the *CipheredTextCount* changes depending on the input.. For example:

```
 $Field = $FW->Encrypt("This is a longer string");
```

The `foreach` loop returns:

> CipheredTextCount = 64
>
> IVCount = 2
>
> KeyCount = 16

and now for my question. Lets take the first example with the TextCount of 44

How can I split a string after `implode("",$Field);` to display as the original array? an example would be:

```
 echo implode("",$Field);
```

Which outputs:

```
ijGglH/vysf52J5aoTaDVHy4oavEBK4mZTrAL3lZMTI=16III#TcTf‡eB12T
```

Based on the results from the `strlen`?

It is possible to store the count of the first `$Cipher_Count` in a database for a reference

---

My current setup involves storing the key and IV in a seperate column away from the ciphered text string.. I need this contained within one field and the script handles the required information to do the following:

> Retrieve The long string > Split string to the original array > Push
>   array to another function > decrypt > return decoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead? Then when you get the data out of the database, you can use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to restore it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Combined_Field =  implode("",$Field);

    echo $str1 = substr($Combined_Field, 0, $Cipher_Count)."<br><br>";
    echo $str2 = substr($Combined_Field,$Cipher_Count,$IV_Count)."<br><br>";
    echo $str3 = substr($Combined_Field, $IV_Count+$Cipher_Count,$Key_Count);
```

Or use a function:

```
function Cipher_Split($Cipher, $Cipher_Count, $KeyCount, $IVCount){
            return array(
                "Ciphered Text" => substr($Cipher,0,$Cipher_Count),
                "IV" => substr($Cipher,$Cipher_Count,$IVCount),
                "Key" => substr($Cipher,$IVCount+$Cipher_Count,$KeyCount)

            );
        }
```